# Matching two different type of equalizer responses

Tags: filter-design, equalization

[AutoEq](https://github.com/jaakkopasanen/AutoEq) (by Jaakko Pasanen) is an utility for headphone equalization. I'm trying to make a EQ converter for [SuperEQ](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/SuperEQ) ([source code](https://github.com/DeaDBeeF-Player/deadbeef/tree/master/plugins/supereq) for implementation found in DeadBeef), which can be found on few software as like Foobar2k Desktop/Mobile and DeaDBeeF (originally SuperEQ was made for Winamp by N. Shibata).

My "problem" is how to "compensate" SuperEQ's EQ response, because of it uses integer step (1dB step) gains at predefined bandwidths? Peaks after AutoEq are not exactly at band center frequencies.

I tried three different approaches by using below configuration for example case of AKG K240 Studio in AutoEq to get the target model (rest is coded with Octave):

```
filter_defaults:
type: PEAKING
  q: 2.871
filters:
  - fc: 55
  - fc: 77
  - fc: 110
  - fc: 156
  - fc: 220
  - fc: 311
  - fc: 440
  - fc: 622
  - fc: 880
  - fc: 1200
  - fc: 1800
  - fc: 2500
  - fc: 3500
  - fc: 5000
  - fc: 7000
  - fc: 10000
  - fc: 14000
  - fc: 20000
```

AutoEq results following gains (dB) for the filtering:

[6.9, 3.7, 0.4, -2.1, -2.6, -1.8, -1.7, -0.1, -2.5, 1.6, 5.4, -3.7, 3.7, 3.9, -2.3, -0.8, 6.5, -13.8];

Octave source code for to calculate target response and **fb2keq1** responses:

```
pkg load signal
pkg load control

clear all;
clf;
format long;


fs = 44100
Q = 2.871
maxfilters = 18

% band center-frequencies
fc = [55, 77, 110, 156, 220, 311, 440, 622, 880, 1200, 1800, 2500, 3500, 5000, 7000, 10000, 14000, 20000];
fcbins = [7676, 8320, 9003, 9672, 10331, 10994, 11658, 12321, 12986, 13580, 14356, 14985, 15630, 16313, 16957, 17640, 18285, 18968];

% bandwidths  
bw = [65, 28, 38, 54, 77, 108, 153, 217, 307, 433, 613, 867, 1226, 1734, 2452, 3468, 4904, 7256];  
low = [20, 65, 93, 131, 185, 262, 370, 523, 740, 1047, 1480, 2093, 2960, 4186, 5920, 8372, 11840, 16744];
high = [65, 93, 131, 185, 262, 370, 523, 740, 1047, 1480, 2093, 2960, 4186, 5920, 8372, 11840, 16744, 24000];

% bins for 44100 Hz sampling
lowbins = [5734, 7992, 8678, 9335, 9996, 10663, 11324, 11987, 12652, 13317, 13980, 14644, 15308, 15972, 16636, 17300, 17964, 18628];
highbins = [7992, 8678, 9335, 9996, 10663, 11324, 11987, 12652, 13317, 13980, 14644, 15308, 15972, 16636, 17300, 17964, 18628, 19317];

% example response  from AutoEq (AKG K240 Studio
AkgG = [6.9, 3.7, 0.4, -2.1, -2.6, -1.8, -1.7, -0.1, -2.5, 1.6, 5.4, -3.7, 3.7, 3.9, -2.3, -0.8, 6.5, -13.8];
AkgQ = []; % not used here (defaulted to 2.871)

fs2 = fs/2;
nf = logspace(0, 5, fs2);

totalmag = zeros(fs2,1);

% Audacity Chirp -tool (Sine, Frequency(Hz): 1:22050, Amplitude (0-1): 0.9:0.9, Interpolation: Logarithmic)
info1 = audioinfo('SWEEP44.1Khz.wav');
[AudioIn, Afs] = audioread('SWEEP44.1Khz.wav');

# ===========================================================================
# fb2keq1
# ===========================================================================

Gbr = [];
for k = 1:maxfilters
  G = AkgG(k);
  a0 = 10^(G/40);
  
  w0 = 2*pi*fc(k)/fs;
  cw0 = cos(w0);
  sw0 = sin(w0);
  alpha = sw0/(2*Q);
  b(1) = 1 + alpha * a0;
  b(2) = -2 * cw0;
  b(3) = 1 - alpha * a0;
  a(1) = 1 + alpha / a0;
  a(2) = -2 * cw0;
  a(3) = 1 - alpha / a0;
  
  % peak filter
  flt = tf(b,a,1/fs);
  
  % filter audio
  AudioIn = filter(b,a,AudioIn);
  
  % total gain after filtering
  [mag, pha, w] = bode(flt,2*pi*nf);
  totalmag = totalmag .+ 20*log10(abs(mag));
  
  figure(1);
  semilogx(nf, 20*log10(abs(mag)), 'g', 'linewidth', 1, 'linestyle', '-');
  hold on;
 
  % compensate gain difference against pk filter gain
  Gbr(k) = (-6.036222963237e-10 * power(G,2) - 1.813054525247e-8 * G - 3.651456691205e-9) * power(k,7);
  Gbr(k) += (3.342484289462e-8 * power(G,2) + 9.845807717647e-7 * G + 2.153219792802e-07) * power(k,6);
  Gbr(k) += (-7.482430938685e-07 *power(G, 2) - 2.165958066742e-05 * G - 5.100731033858e-06) * power(k,5);
  Gbr(k) += (8.633896438672e-06 * power(G,2) + 2.388711394478e-04 * G + 6.185852688288e-05) * power(k,4);
  Gbr(k) += (-5.397314203515e-05 * power(G,2) - 1.375407442728e-03 * G - 4.051922973033e-04) * power(k,3);
  Gbr(k) += (1.779969763859e-04 * power(G,2) + 3.686956553952e-03 * G + 1.394132158502e-03) * power(k,2);
  Gbr(k) += (-2.683209992000e-04 * power(G, 2) - 3.385508164870e-03 * G - 2.217879704680e-03) * k;
  Gbr(k) += (3.000406258592e-03 * power(G,2) + 2.988955753376e-02 * G + 1.154757109207e-02);
  Gbr(k) += G;
  Gbr(k) = int32(Gbr(k));
 
  semilogx([low(k),high(k)],[Gbr(k), Gbr(k)], '0-m', 'linewidth', 2);
  hold on;
  semilogx([low(k),low(k)],[0,Gbr(k)], 'm','linewidth', 1);
  hold on;
  semilogx([high(k),high(k)],[Gbr(k) 0], 'm','linewidth', 1);
  hold on;

endfor

% data for Foobar2000 EQ preset
printf('fb2keq1 preset\n');
for k = 1:18
  printf('%i \n', Gbr(k));
endfor

% save target ressponse
audiowrite('targeteq441.wav', AudioIn * 0.5, Afs);

xlabel('Hz'); ylabel('dB');
axis([20 20000 -15 9]);
grid on;

% plot target
semilogx(nf,totalmag,'linestyle', '--', 'linewidth', 2, 'r');

% W1441.wav is generated using Audacity for record Foobar2000 output while 
% foobar EQ uses preset got from Gbr.
info1 = audioinfo('W1441.wav');
[AudioFBK0, Ffs] = audioread('W1441.wav');
```

Here's plot showing results I got for [AKG K240 Studio](https://github.com/jaakkopasanen/AutoEq/tree/master/results/oratory1990/over-ear/AKG%20K240%20Studio) case :

[image]

where responses are:

green lines = responses of each 18 peaking filters ( in EQ one maybe likes to use shelf filters at lowest/highest freqs ),

red dashed line = response of summed 18 peaking filters ( = EQ for AKG K240 Studio here ) and

**fb2keq1** calculations are based on gains of each peaking filter (gain of the "bar" @ 55Hz = total gain of peaking filter @ 55Hz, etc.) :

[image]

Illustration of method used: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eql4ij7tgs

**fb2keq2** is calculated by splitting summed EQ (target) to equal bandwidths as which SuperEQ uses, then calculated total gain for each band separately and finally adjusted gains for SuperEQ bands by those numbers :

[image]

Source code for to calculate/plot **fb2keq2** responses (add to the end of previous source listings):

```
# ===========================================================================
# fb2keq2
# ===========================================================================
% calculate total gains in every bw for each pk filter and adjust gain for bar eq's 
% by that info

fb2keq2 = [];
for f = 1:maxfilters
  tot = 0;
  bins = 0;
  for g = lowbins(f):highbins(f)
    if (g > fs2) 
      break;
    endif
    bins += 1;
    tot += int32(totalmag(g));
  endfor
  fb2keq2(f) = tot/bins;
endfor

% final rounded gains for fb2keq2 
for k = 1:maxfilters
  G = int32(fb2keq2(k));
  semilogx([low(k),high(k)],[G, G], 'k', 'linestyle', '--', 'linewidth', 2);
  hold on;
  semilogx([low(k),low(k)],[0,G], 'k','linestyle', '--', 'linewidth', 1);
  hold on;
  semilogx([high(k),high(k)],[G 0], 'k','linestyle', '--', 'linewidth', 1);
  hold on;
endfor

% data for Foobar200o EQ preset
printf('fb2keq2 preset\n');
for k = 1:18
  printf('%i \n', int32(fb2keq2(k)));
endfor

% W2441.wav is generated using Audacity for record Foobar2000 output while 
% foobar EQ uses preset got from int32(fb2keq2(k)).
info1 = audioinfo('W2441.wav');
[AudioFBK1, Ffs] = audioread('W2441.wav');
```

**fb2keq3**  is calculated by matching center of each bandwidth (bar) at target curve :

[image]

Source code for to calculate/plot **fb2keq3** responses (add to the end of previous source listings):

```
# ===========================================================================
# fb2keq3
# ===========================================================================     
% follow combined curve
for k = 1:maxfilters
  G = int32(totalmag(fcbins(k)));
  semilogx([low(k),high(k)],[G, G], 'linestyle', ':', '0-b', 'linewidth', 2);
  hold on;
  semilogx([low(k),low(k)],[0,G], 'linestyle', ':', 'b','linewidth', 1);
  hold on;
  semilogx([high(k),high(k)],[G 0], 'linestyle', ':', 'b','linewidth', 1);
  hold on;
endfor

% data for Foobar200o EQ preset
printf('fb2keq3 preset\n');
for k = 1:18
  printf('%i \n', int32(totalmag(fcbins(k))));
endfor

% W3441.wav is generated using Audacity for record Foobar2000 output while 
% foobar EQ uses preset got from int32(totalmag(fcbins(k))).
info1 = audioinfo('W3441.wav');
[AudioFBK2, Ffs] = audioread('W3441.wav');
```

Source code for to plot audio data (add to the end of previous source listings):

```
# PLOT AUDIO FILES ============================================================
nf2 = logspace(0, 5, fs);  
figure(2);

% target 
p4 = semilogx(nf2, AudioIn .* 0.5, 'b');
hold on;

%% CHECK/FIX !! Corrected y -offsets (somehow EQ'ed data got from Audacity was little off)
p1 = semilogx(nf2, AudioFBK0 .+ 0.06, 'c');
hold on;
##p2 = semilogx(nf2, (AudioFBK1 .+ 0.05), 'c');
#hold on;
#p3 = semilogx(nf2, AudioFBK2 .+  0.06, 'c');
##hold on;

legend('Target', 'FoobarEQ','location', 'northwest');
xlabel('Sample'); ylabel('Amplitude');
axis([20 20000 -1.3 1.3]);
grid on;
```

! (audio files generated by playing clean/flat sweep signal (1Hz-20kHz) with Foobar2k build-in EQ enabled (and set by result values) and recorded using Audacity)?

Are there other methods/theories available to do this kind of 'matching' the curve (isn't this kind of A-D conversion in question so in that area of theories might found something useful ...)?

Comment: From the Super EQ website `here is currently no text in this page. You can search for this page title in other pages, or search the related logs.` I think we need a bit more detail than that :-)

Comment: Sorry, link was corrupted when pasting it ... fixed now

Comment: uhm, those swept sinusoids?  Do you have a nice equation defining them?  are they exponentially increasing sweeps?

To me it looks like the filter design alg is working quite well.

Comment: I'll add some Octave code later. Base sweep signal is generated using Audacity Chirp tool (sine, 1Hz-20kHz, 0.9 flat amplitude, logarithmic interpolation).

Comment: By *"logarithmic interpolation"*, does that mean that the instantaneous frequency doubles every equal segment of time? And that there is an equal amount of energy each octave?

Comment: Audacity source code should answer this : https://github.com/audacity/audacity/blob/master/src/effects/ToneGen.cpp